# Postscript printing: Removing the information box at the top of buffer

Tags: print

When printing a buffer (for example with the Printing package), I understand Emacs coverts it into a Postscript file and then prints this file. But this Postscript file always contains a grey box at the top, displaying information about the buffer (name of the buffer, path, date, number of pages), which prefaces the actual buffer I want to print. After some research I haven't got any idea how to remove this box.

In other words, I would like the content of my buffer, and only that, to be sent to the printer.

Comment: `(setq ps-print-header nil)`?

Comment: That's it ! Thanks a lot Arash Esbati ! Can I ask you how you got to know that ?

Comment: Usually, .el files have a `;;; Commentary:` section at the beginning with useful information about usage and/or implementation.  You can read the file itself with `M-x find-library RET ps-print RET` or only that section with `M-x describe-package RET ps-print RET`.  I read it once as I wanted to adjust some other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by Arash Esbati in a comment to my question: the variable `ps-print-header` needs to be changed to `nil`.
By the way, other variables related to Postscript printing can be `customize`d.